# Google Maps InfoBubble windows neither closing nor recentering map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a successful working *GM* prototype using InfoBubble [here](http://gettylabs.org/visit/FoundationMap/IBnotcloseNotCenter.html).

I need the map to **recenter when I open each new** InfoBubble window.

The map recenters on closing each InfoBubble because I call [line 238 etc]:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoBubble, "closeclick", function ()
```

Secondly, why doesn't the Los Angeles (United States West Coast, LA) InfoBubble also close the most recent InfoBubble window open as all the others do, please?

Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions; I know it must be simple - but have spent hours and hours and searched S/O too!

javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { initialize();  });
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.30, 0.7);
    function initialize() {
        google.maps.Map.prototype.setCenterWithOffset = function(LatLng, offsetX, offsetY) {
            var map = this;
            var ov = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            ov.onAdd = function() {
                var proj = this.getProjection();
                var aPoint = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(LatLng);
                aPoint.x = aPoint.x+offsetX;
                aPoint.y = aPoint.y+offsetY;
                map.setCenter(proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(aPoint));
            }; 
            ov.draw = function() {}; 
            ov.setMap(this); 
        };
        var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(51.30, 0.7);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            draggable: false,
            center: centerMap,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setCenterWithOffset(myLatlng, 50, 225);
        setMarkers(map, sites);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infoBubble, "closeclick", function () {
            map.setCenterWithOffset(myLatlng, 50, 225);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(infoBubbleLA, "closeclick", function () {
            map.setCenterWithOffset(myLatlng, 50, 225);
        });
    };

    var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        maxWidth: 400,
    });

    var infoBubbleLA = new InfoBubble({
        maxWidth: 400,
    });

 // locationstrings start
    var losangeles1 = 'losangeles1';
    var losangeles2 = 'losangeles2';
    var losangeles3 = 'losangeles3';
    var losangeles4 = 'losangeles4';
    var losangelescontentString ='losangelescontentString';
    var portonovocontentstring ='Porto Novo';
    var shackletoncontentstring = 'Shackleton';
    var florencecontentstring = 'Florence';
    var buenosairescontentstring = 'Buenos Aires';
    var jodhpurcontentstring = 'Jodhpur';
    var mtsinaicontentstring = 'Mt Sainai';
    var neworleanscontentstring = 'New Orleans';
    var pariscontentstring='Paris';

 // locationstrings end

    infoBubbleLA.addTab('Electronic Cataloguing Initiative', losangeles1);
    infoBubbleLA.addTab('Getty Leadership Institute at Claremont Graduate University', losangeles2);
    infoBubbleLA.addTab('Tab 3', losangeles3);
    infoBubbleLA.addTab('Preserve L.A.', losangeles4);

    var sites = [
    //   'Title',        lat,      long,       contentstring
        ['Los Angeles', 34.054082,-118.24261, losangelescontentString],
        ['Porto Novo', 6.501411,2.604275, portonovocontentstring],
        ['Shackleton', -77.550000, 166.150000, shackletoncontentstring],
        ['Florence', 43.773046,11.255901, florencecontentstring],
        ['Buenos Aires', -34.578528,-58.526273, buenosairescontentstring],
        ['Jodhpur', 27.199507,73.73826, jodhpurcontentstring],
        ['Mt Sinai', 28.555972,33.975048, mtsinaicontentstring],
        ['New Orleans', 29.984676,-90.063171, neworleanscontentstring],
        ['Paris', 48.821799,2.404933, pariscontentstring]
    ];

    var iconBase = 'http://gettylabs.org/visit/FoundationMap/images/';
    function setMarkers(map, markers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var sites = markers[i];
            var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: iconBase + 'bullet.png',
                title: sites[0],
                position: siteLatLng,
                html: sites[3],
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                map.setCenterWithOffset(myLatlng, 50, 25);
                if (this.html == losangelescontentString) {
                    infoBubbleLA.setContent(this.html);
                    infoBubbleLA.open(map,this);
                } else {
                    infoBubble.setContent(this.html);
                    infoBubble.open(map,this);
                }
            });
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different InfoBubbles in you code infoBubbleLA and infoBubble.  Opening one won't close the the other.

```
    var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        maxWidth: 400,
    });

    var infoBubbleLA = new InfoBubble({
        maxWidth: 400,
    });
```

This should do that:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                map.setCenterWithOffset(myLatlng, 50, 25);
                if (this.html == losangelescontentString) {
                    infoBubbleLA.setContent(this.html);
                    infoBubbleLA.open(map,this);
                    infoBubble.close();
                } else {
                    infoBubble.setContent(this.html);
                    infoBubble.open(map,this);
                    infoBubbleLA.close();
                }
            });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ejxk4gy/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thanks, geocode zip! Have fixed the double bubble. But the map still does not center. Thanks for any ideas on that which you may have, please :-)

Comment: geocodezip, Thanks! But with the zoom level which I have to use (http://gettylabs.org/visit/FoundationMap/IBnotcloseNotCenter.html) the marker/window in the very bottom right (Antarctica, Shackleton's Hut) disappears off the map this way. I really want each time a new window opens for the entire map to recenter in the same way as it does when I close a window.